# Is there any way we can convert our angular page to pdf and pass it to the application's document upload service without downloading the file?

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf-generation

I want to convert my page to pdf and directly upload it using upload service without downloading the file in the system.

I tried using jspdf but can't see a option just to convert to pdf instead save method is downloading the pdf file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Consider a Document Conversion library like the LEADTOOLS [Document Converter SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-converter). The returned result from the [Convert](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/javascript/dox/leaddocument-convert.html) method for a LEADDocument object, once complete, can be forwarded to the upload service. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor).